# Enviar uma requisição post com ajax para PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Estou tentando enviar um texto que é digitado via ajax para para uma página php que vai fazer uma consulta utilizando esse texto que é recebido. Quero saber como envio o valor da variável `nmCliente` para a página php. Eu tentei o seguinte código e o retorno foi `500 (Internal Server Error)`. Estou utilizando o framework [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)

Seguem os códigos.

Jquery

```
                var nmCliente = $("#nome").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../buscacliente",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: nmCliente,
                    dataType: "text"

                }).done(function(resposta) {
                    console.log(resposta);

                }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);

                }).always(function() {
                    console.log("completou");
                });
```

PHP

```
/**
 * @Route("/buscacliente", name="busca_cliente")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */

public function buscaContratoAction(Request $resquest)
{
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => 'this is a json response'));
    }

    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

Comment: O erro 500 é provavelmente pelo uso de `../` na URL. O sistema de arquivos é totalmente diferente da URL (apesar de parecerem similares). Veja [aqui](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/551838-problemas-com-url-lado-servidor/), [aqui](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/550543-definir-caminho-dos-arquivos/) ou [aqui (inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44136410/1628790). De qualquer forma, utilize URL absoluta no AJAX. No links acima há exemplos.

Comment: A URL está correta, é uma padrão que tem que ser usado nesse framework. Se eu mudar alguma coisa a resposta é `404 (Not Found)

Comment: A única menção que está correta é que se mudar da erro 404. Mas padrão de framework não é. Além disso `../` é nem um pouco recomendado ([pode verificar formas recomendas aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/1628790) ou como o [framework usa com twig aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13585748/1628790)). Entretanto, se não está causando o problema, verifique os logs do servidor. Erro 500 é erro de servidor e não quer dizer nada além disso.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, você precisa utilizar o bundle [FosJsRouting](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html) na sua aplicação do symfony. É extremamente recomendado, e não tem segredo pra utilizar a biblioteca!
Quando tiver tudo instalado e funcionando, você vai utilizar no parametro dentro do annotation `options={"expose"=true}`, de acordo com o exemplo a seguir:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo/{id}/bar", options={"expose"=true}, name="my_route_to_expose")
 */
  public function indexAction($foo) {
   // ...
  }
```

E no javascript você irá chamar a rota através da função `Routing.generate()`.

```
          var url = Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 });
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: nmCliente,
                dataType: "text"

            }).done(function(resposta) {
                console.log(resposta);

            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);

            }).always(function() {
                console.log("completou");
            });
```

Vai funcionar legal! Abraço!